# How do I get the value of a users input and then convert it to HH:MM format in javascript or jquery using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I read that moment.js would do the trick, and have it included in my files but I don't know where to start. I need to get the value from an input field (#enterClockIn), convert it to HH:MM, and then once I have that value, I need to be able to add/subtract hours and minutes from it.

I currently have 1 function that is triggered by a click and would like to include this new code right into it so everything calculates at once. Here's is my codepen for this project:

https://codepen.io/lgrizo/pen/LLxbab

HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <h3>Workweek Calculator</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections totalHours">How many hours do you plan on working this week?</h4>
      <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="userInput" id="hoursThisWeek" placeholder="ex: 40" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections fridayHours">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
      <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="userInput" id="fridayMorning" placeholder="ex:  33">
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections remDecimal">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
      <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="userInput" id="remainingDecimals" placeholder="ex:  .57" />
    </div>


    <div>
      <h4 class="sections clockFriday">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
      <input type="text" maxlength="8" class="userInput" id="enterClockIn" placeholder="ex:  07:22 AM" /><br />
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="buttons">
      <button class="amButton">AM</button>
      <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
    </div> -->

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections lunch">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
      <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="userInput" id="enterLunch" placeholder="ex: 30"/>
    </div>

    <div class="sections calculate">
      <button class="calcButton" onclick="calculateButton()">Calculate my hours</button>
    </div>

    <div class="resultsDiv">

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections currentHoursWorked results">Current hours worked:</h4>
      <output type="text" class="defaultCalc resultsCalc" id="currentWorked">

      </output>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections remainHours results">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
      <output type="text" class="defaultCalc resultsCalc" id="hoursLeftToWork">

      </output>
    </div>

    <div>

      <div>
        <h4 class="sections remainHours results">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
        <output type="text" class="defaultCalc clockOutTime resultsCalc" id="currentWorked">

        </output>
      </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/moment.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/*Base style layouts*/

header, body {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #96deda 0%, #50c9c3 40%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 14.5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/

.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
}



.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 14.5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*this removed the box shadow that was showing up on safari mobile*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Buttons*/

.amButton, .pmButton {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #50c9c3;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
}


.clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

output:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.userInput:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid #50c9c3;
}


.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.175em;
}

#currentWorked,
#hoursLeftToWork {
  width: 180px;
  height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #60B6FF;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 575px;
  }

  .resultsDiv {
    width: 650px;
  }

  .results {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }

  .totalHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .fridayHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .remDecimal {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .clockFriday {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .buttons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }

  .amButton, .pmButton {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .lunch {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .lastButtons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
  }
  .clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .sections, .clockOutTime, .defaultCalc {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .calcButton {
    width: 520px;
  }

}
```

JS

```
function calculateButton() {

  // this gets the value for the "hours planned on working this week" field
  var hoursThisWeek = parseInt(document.getElementById('hoursThisWeek').value);

  // current hours on friday morning
  var fridayMorning = parseInt(document.getElementById('fridayMorning').value);

  // ramaining minutes in decimal form
  var remainingDecimals = (document.getElementById('remainingDecimals').value);

  //convert decimal minutes into time format minutes rounded to the nearest whole number
  var roundedDecimal = Math.round(remainingDecimals * 60);

  //result for current hours worked
  var currentWorked = fridayMorning + " hours " + roundedDecimal + " minutes";


  var remainingHours = (hoursThisWeek - fridayMorning) - 1;

  var remainingMinutes = (60 - roundedDecimal);

  var hoursLeftToWork = remainingHours + " hours " + remainingMinutes + " minutes";



  //this is to display the current hours worked results
  document.getElementById('currentWorked').innerHTML = currentWorked;

  //this is to display the remaining hours left results
  document.getElementById('hoursLeftToWork').innerHTML = hoursLeftToWork;



}

//Here is where I'm stuck! Do I start by getting the value from this input field? 
  var clockIn = $('#enterClockIn').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you split the friday morning how many hour and decimals into different inputs? makes you write more code that way..

also you need to read the momentjs docs. they are extremely helpful. https://momentjs.com/docs/

Overall, what you had to do was tell moment the friday clock in time format (it would be `hh:mm A`) and then add the minutes to it

(eg `moment("07:00 AM", "hh:mm A").add("90","minutes")` will result in `08:30 AM`)

Basically:

```
var clockOutTime = moment(clockedInFri, "hh:mm A").add(remaining + lunchBreak, "minutes");
clockOutTime = clockOutTime.format("hh:mm A");
```

Here is the full pen: https://codepen.io/nodirashidov/pen/WORMNZ

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to read through the momentjs docs but I can't make much sense of it being that this is all new to me. Everything seems to be working with your new code, except the fact that if you enter .34 as the remaining decimal, your result with show up as "33 hours and 20.40000000009 minutes". This is what my original math.round method was supposed to correct in the original "roundedDecimal" variable. How can I fix this now?

Comment: Actually, something is off here. It seems like certain values are returning incorrect "clock out times".  For example, if I enter .34 as the remaining decimal, the clock out time makes sense. But if I enter .65, the clock out time is completely incorrect. Weird..

Comment: sorry i forgot to add a parseInt() to lunch break, so javascript was taking that value as a string instead of an integer. Now the same pen should be working

Comment: as for the momentjs. basically, what you need to know is `moment()` creates an object of current date and time (try `console.log(moment());`). you can use `moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD")`to convert the object into a string in the format the user can understand. in your case, doing (`moment(someVar, "hh:mm A)` sends your someVar to moment and tells in what format you are sending it. So moment converts someVar into the object. someVar does not have a date, only time. so moment adds today's date to the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything seems to be working great now. Learned a lot from this exchange. Going back to one of your questions, the excel spreadsheet that I got this idea from had two separate sections for the friday hours in whole number, and then another cell for the decimals which is I just did it the same way. I wish i would have combined them from the beginning. I am going to try to figure out how to combine the Friday hours and the decimals into one field. Wish me luck!